# Launching an GUI app with udev rule after plugging in usb?

Tags: udev

so Im trying to run gui app with udev but with 0 success,

I read somewhere that i have to find Xauthority file, and put display variable in scripts, Is this right, and if yes could someone write an example script?

Thank you in advance :)

MY CURRENT SETUP :

```
SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", ATTRS{idProduct}=="1337", ACTION=="add", RUN+="/usr/local/bin/New.sh"
```

Script `New.sh`

```
#!/bin/sh
./New2.sh & exit
```

Script `New2.sh`

```
#!/bin/sh
vlc v4l2:///dev/video0
```

Comment: added in original question

Comment: First problem is that current directory is undefined. So `./New2 sh` won't look in the right place. You'll need to change that to an absolute path. I'd suggest you use `logger` to provide a trace of what's going on. You'll see the output in somewhere such as `/var/log/user.log`. Try `logger 'This is a test'` and then `grep -l 'This is a test' /var/log/*` to find out for sure.

Comment: Second problem is that there is no permission for `vlc` to write to your display, and it doesn't know what display to use. Take a look at similar questions here asking about running a GUI app from `cron`. It's the same set of issues you need to address.

Comment: @roaima here is the solution you have proposed: https://askubuntu.com/a/514449/63062 .

Answer (score 1):

Follow my working solution for a Samsung Android device...

Write a script in `/etc/udev/rules.d` like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

su <NON_ROOT_USER> -c <YOUR_GUI_APPLICATION>
```

Run `udevadm monitor -e` to get your device path (e.g. `/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:04:00.3/usb1/1-2`) and write down it.

Run `udevadm info -ap <YOUR_DEVICE_PATH>` to get rules to put into your udev configuration folder. E.g.

```
  ACTION=="add" \
, SUBSYSTEM=="usb" \
, ENV{DEVTYPE}=="usb_device" \
, ATTRS{idVendor}=="04e8" \
, ATTRS{idProduct}=="6860" \
, ATTR{product}=="SAMSUNG_Android" \
, ATTR{serial}=="R58MC3542ZX"
```

Write a script named `50-my-android-device.rules` into`/etc/udev/rules.d` like this:

```
  ACTION=="add" \
, SUBSYSTEM=="usb" \
, ENV{DEVTYPE}=="usb_device" \
, ATTRS{idVendor}=="04e8" \
, ATTRS{idProduct}=="6860" \
, ATTR{product}=="SAMSUNG_Android" \
, ATTR{serial}=="R58MC3542ZX" \
, ENV{DISPLAY}=":0.0" \
, RUN+="/etc/udev/rules.d/<MY_RUNNABLE.SCRIPT>"
```